# pulling only changes from repo git

Tags: git, github

im using git for update my website and i update the repo from my notebook, then before i push the changes, i have to clone the repo to the public_http folder

there is any way to clone only the last changes???

or i have to clone everychange??

the problem is that im working on windows 7 with msysgit and tortoisegit, on server is debian 64bits and git-core and gitolite installed... the push changes works fine but the problem is that when i have to clone the repo to public_http folder i have to recompile some modules because there are compiled for windows so i have to compile again for debian in every clone proccess... tnx all

Comment: add node_modules to your .gitignore so you don't need to recompile each time

Answer (score 0):

Why are you cloning into public_http?!  Every time you clone you create a .git repository; but once you've got a .git repository all you need to do is 'git pull'.  That is, the normal use is to 'git clone' once followed by 'git pull' repeatedly.

Assume you have a shared repository (like on github).  You do your development on your notebook, using your local .git repository.  When you are ready to update your website you then 'git push origin' (assume 'origin' is on github).  After that you log into your web service site, stop your webserver, perform 'git pull origin', recompile as needed, restart your webserver.